# Spark SQL - Delay between job (Broadcast DataFrame)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I have an application that process 8 dataframes on an parallel iteration. The job had ran fine, until I included a join of those dataframes with two really small dataframes (less than 1kb) that are generated reading a csv files. After the join was included, the application execution time increased a lot (more than 100%). Looking at the spark Web UI I found some jobs with the follow description run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149. These jobs are responsible for Broadcast the very small dataframes. Those jobs run for each small dataframe for each parallel execution (16 times). And the delay for each ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149 execution chunk is about 4 minutes. The problem is increasing, at the same pace I added a new small dataframe that joins with the 8 parallel dataframes.

To parallelize the dataframes I created a List[DataFrame].par

-Here the object to read and generate the csv dataframes:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

// s"${dataBaseParameters.viewConfigurationDir}view_classification_by_path_clean.csv
 //view_classification_by_subtype.csv"
 //view_classification_by_type.csv"

object ClassificationOverwriteLoader {

 def loadViewClassification (spark: SparkSession, schema: StructType, filePath: String): DataFrame = {
   spark.read
     .format("csv")
     .option("header", "true")
     .option("delimiter", ";")
     .schema(schema)
     .load(filePath)
 }

 val ByPathSchema = StructType(
   Seq(
     StructField("path_clean", StringType,true),
     StructField("group_override_by_path", StringType, true),
     StructField("type_override_by_path", StringType, true),
     StructField("subtype_override_by_path", StringType, true),
     StructField("is_active", BooleanType,true),
     StructField("row_created_date", DateType,true),
     StructField("row_updated_date", DateType,true),
     StructField("row_created_by", StringType,true),
     StructField("row_updated_by", StringType,true)
   )
 )

 val ByTypeSubTypeSchema = StructType(
   Seq(
     StructField("group_override", StringType, true),
     StructField("type_source", StringType, true),
     StructField("type_override", StringType, true),
     StructField("subtype_source", StringType, true),
     StructField("subtype_override", StringType, true),
     StructField("is_active", BooleanType,true),
     StructField("row_created_date", DateType,true),
     StructField("row_updated_date", DateType,true),
     StructField("row_created_by", StringType,true),
     StructField("row_updated_by", StringType,true)
   )
 )

}
```

[Spark UI with the delay between jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC1bL.png)

I'm running this job on a Google DataProc cluster, and all the data is storage on Google File System (include the csv files). Is there a way to avoid this scheduling delay?

Comment: It looks like the delay between jobs is not a cause but an effect of introducing join. You might need to digg deeper to figure out the real bottleneck.